# weird behavior of python 2.7 swap

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to swap the 1st element (`4`) with the 3rd element (`1`) for list `[-1,4,3,1]`, I expect output is `[-1, 1, 3, 4]`, but why output is `[4, 1, 3, 1]`?

Using Python 2.7.

```
a=[-1,4,3,1]
i=1
a[i],a[a[i]-1]=a[a[i]-1],a[i]
print a # output [4, 1, 3, 1]
# expect [-1, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The values are assigned to the targets on the left-hand side in order from left to right.  So after the first value is assigned to `a[i]`, the value of `a[i]` is changed, and this new value is used to compute the assignment to `a[a[i]-1]`.

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn, nice catch! But isn't Python swap behavior assignment in parallel?

Comment: @LinMa: That depends what you mean by "parallel".  All of the values on the right are computed before any assignment is done, so a simple swap like `a, b = b, a` will work.  The assignment may appear to be "parallel" as long as the targets on the left do not reference each other.  But if any of the targets on the left depend on other targets on the left, they can influence each other.

Answer (score 0):

> In an assignment statement, the right-hand side is always evaluated
>   fully before doing the actual variable assignment.

```
a[i],a[a[i]-1] = a[a[i]-1],a[i] 
# is Equal to
a[i], a[a[i]-1] = 1, 4
```

Actual variable assignment from left to right

```
a[i], a[a[i]-1] = 1, 4
# is same as
a[i] = 1
a[1-1] = 4
```

That why you got the [4, 1, 3, 1] result.
With BrenBarn explanation you can do somethings like this

```
a[a[i]-1], a[i] = a[i], a[a[i]-1] # return [-1, 1, 3, 4]
```